# What does it mean by "Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 14"

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

when start a project i get this error in android studio

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] C:\Users\max.android\build-cache\794d310f97f0ec38ea2a53aafb733961774fb930\output\AndroidManifest.xml
>       Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.appcompat" to force usage

Comment: You started a brand new project? What minimum sdk did you use?

Comment: change ur minSdkVersion from 9 to 14 in your project level gradle.

Comment: i need it run start from android 2.3

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43173107

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that Your project uses library with minimum SDK 14 and in Your app You've set it to 9. Minimum SDK for the main project and libraries should be same.

Comment: how to make the library the same 
there is only one com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1

Comment: try using older appcompat

Answer (score 0):

you can resolve this problem by just changing minSdkVersion from 9 to 14 in build.gradle(Module app) file of your app and then sync the project