# I got this error while loading Android studio

Tags: android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

```
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1] /home/dinesh/.android/build-cache/5b4541f0362f0c186bfecf0c7160b9688c35a715/output/AndroidManifest.xml
    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.design" to force usage
```

Comment: change your project min sdk to 14 or higher

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does it mean by "Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 14"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44485095/what-does-it-mean-by-manifest-merger-failed-uses-sdkminsdkversion-9-cannot-b)

Comment: Read your logcat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build app supports Old SDK Versions (minSdkVersion) in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44604854/how-to-build-app-supports-old-sdk-versions-minsdkversion-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

It is self explanatory. The library which you are using in your app has min sdk version set to 14.

But in your app you have set it to 9.

Now you need to increase it to minimum 14.

Answer (score 0):

- in `app/build.gradle`, `minSdkVersion` should not be smaller than 14

Answer (score 0):

Set your project to use SDK version 25.0.0. Ensure it is downloaded first in Android SDK settings found under Tools > Android > SDK Manager. Search for SDK Settings and look under SDK Tools. Ensure Show Package Details is checked.

Then change your app/build.gradle to have 25.0.0 used in place of what put there by default if you used the wizard to create your app. e.g.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.adam.myapplication5"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

You can change the Sdk version, the buildToolsVersion and targetSdkVersion via the File > Project Structure > Properties and Flavors tabs. But I found the need to set the compile directives manually via editing the build.gradle file directly.