# How to build app supports Old SDK Versions (minSdkVersion) in android

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

When creating new project by wizard and gives errors, then it is so frustrated.

I just create new project with MinSdk = 9 to make the app run on gingerbread
this gives me the following Error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] C:\Users\USER\.android\build-cache\dfb3187f39ea1ff94009f5d34353fff5cfc3daee\output\AndroidManifest.xml
    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.appcompat" to force usage
```

and here is the gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.com.testApp"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

how to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use the older version of the support library.

`compileSdkVersion 25`

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
```

As you can find out in the releases notes for 26.0.0 [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#26-0-0-alpha1)

> Note: The minimum SDK version has been increased to 14. As a result,
>   many APIs that existed only for API < 14 compatibility have been
>   deprecated. Clients of these APIs should migrate to their framework
>   equivalents as noted in the reference page for each deprecated API.

Comment: how to get old version of support library ?

Comment: [Adding Support Libraries] (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html#add-library)

Comment: when installing support library by SDK Manager it delete the old release, and install the new one, in my case I have android studio 2.3.3 with com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1, so when trying to use 25.4.0 with buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'  it did works, gradle gives Error:(27, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0
 Install Repository and sync project ...

Comment: You don't have to use SDK Manager to get the support library anymore. Use Google's Maven repository, it is more convinient. Please follow instructions in provided link from my previous comment.

Comment: when use compileSdkVersion 25 gives error Error:(27, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0
<a href="install.m2.repo">Install Repository and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile:E:/mylab/andoridStudio23/MyApplication/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>

Comment: if you have steps to follow how to downgrade to 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0' how to build android project supports SDK 9 after installing sdk platform build tools and platform tools 8 api 26 please write it these steps here

Comment: Set 25 for targetSdkVersion  and compileSdkVersion. Add to your project's build.gradle file new section with Google's maven repository. Everything is described in the link from my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'`

Or change `compileSdkVersion 26` to `compileSdkVersion 25` and use a library from that version

Comment: I tried this but without success when use compileSdkVersion 25 gives error Error:(27, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0 Install Repository and sync project

Comment: is there any way to manually download appcompat support library ? or is there any way to work with muliple releases of appcompat ? my problem appears after update support library to 26.0.0-alpha1 without hope to download old releases